# Accessing functions in the class modules of nn.Sequential

Tags: pytorch

When running nn.Sequential, I include a list of class modules (which would be layers of a neural network). When running nn.Sequential, it calls forward functions of the modules. However each of the class modules also has a function which I would like to access when the nn.Sequential runs. How can I access and run this function when running nn.Sequential?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **hook** for that. Let's consider the following example demonstrated on *VGG16*:

This is the network architecture:

[image]

Say we want to monitor the input and output for layer (2)  in the *features* `Sequential` (that Conv2d layer you see above).
For this matter we register a forward hook, named `my_hook` which will be called on any forward pass:

```py
import torch
from torchvision.models import vgg16

def my_hook(self, input, output):
    print('my_hook\'s output')
    print('input: ', input)
    print('output: ', output)

# Sample net:
net = vgg16()

#Register forward hook:
net.features[2].register_forward_hook(my_hook)

# Test:
img = torch.randn(1,3,512,512)
out = net(img) # Will trigger my_hook and the data you are looking for will be printed
```